# How to get Header value of MenuItem from custom Binding?

Tags: wpf, menuitem, commandbinding, custom-binding

I have defined **RoutedCommand** in my class and in XAML

```
Public Shared CustomCommandShowAll As New RoutedCommand

Public Shared CustomCommandFirstPage As New RoutedCommand

Public Shared CustomCommandSecondPage As New RoutedCommand



<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:DynamicTab.CustomCommandShowAll" Executed="ShowAll_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="local:DynamicTab.CustomCommandFirstPage" Executed="FirstPage_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="local:DynamicTab.CustomCommandSecondPage" Executed="Secondpage_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="local:DynamicTab.CustomCommandShowAll" Key="F1" Modifiers="Alt"/>
        <KeyBinding Command="local:DynamicTab.CustomCommandFirstPage" Key="F2" Modifiers="Alt"/>
        <KeyBinding Command="local:DynamicTab.CustomCommandSecondPage" Key="F3" Modifiers="Alt"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

These bindings are hooked up by **Menuitems**

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" >

                <MenuItem x:Name="filtermenu" Header="_FilterType" BorderBrush="White" >

                    <MenuItem Header="ShowAll" IsChecked="True" InputGestureText="Alt+F1"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="FirstPage" InputGestureText="Alt+F2"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="Secondpage" InputGestureText="Alt+F3"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
```

Now, when i press <kbd>ALT+F1</kbd> , **`ShowAll_Executed`** Method will get a call and here i have two Parameters **`ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs`**

```
    Private Sub ShowAll_Executed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

I don know how to get the **ShowAll** **MenuItem Header Name** from these two parameters, if i get the value, i can use only one **RoutedCommand** for all three MenuItems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need it? `Alt+F1` is not linked to `MenuItem` and when pressed `sender` in `ShowAll_Executed` will point to a `Window` as that's where `InputBinding` is defined. Also your `MenuItem` will not call any command when you click on it as [`InputGestureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext.aspx) is just text. It does not do any input bindings. `MenuItem` has its own `Command` executed when clicked.

Comment: @dkozl , Thanks for reply, by the way , Is there any possible way to get the name of the menuitem? If so please provide.